# How to set up a TYPO3 project with docker

Tags: docker, composer-php, typo3

I want to create a new project in docker. 
I have already setup docker. Then install TYPO3 inside of it.

My docker file

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: Please consider adding some code (Dockerfile in your case) to show what you have tried.

Comment: Step 1 is to start with PHP instead of Python

Comment: ok then what will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several projects dealing with [TYPO3](https://typo3.org) in a [Docker container](https://www.docker.com).

Two well-known and active projects are the "TYPO3 Docker Boilerplate" by [webdevops.io](https://webdevops.io) and some documents written and published by [Martin Helmich](https://www.martin-helmich.de).

**TYPO3 Docker Boilerplate** [[link](https://webdevops.io/projects/typo3-docker-boilerplate/)][[GitHub](https://github.com/webdevops/TYPO3-docker-boilerplate)]
This is a pre-configured Docker image to allow a simple setup for any TYPO3 related project. This boilerplate enables you to kickstart a TYPO3 Project and provides optional services commonly used in the TYPO3 world, such as [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for example.

**Martin Helmich** [[link](https://www.martin-helmich.de/en/blog/typo3-cms-docker.html)]
Comprehensive blog article by Martin Helmich, who also provides Docker images at [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/r/martinhelmich/typo3/)

[UPDATE] A third project worth mentioning is [DDEV](https://www.drud.com/what-is-ddev/) -- an open source tool based on Docker, that makes it simple to get a local PHP development environment. It is well documented in the official TYPO3 documentation ([Contribution Workflow Guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ContributionWorkflowGuide/Appendix/SettingUpTypo3Ddev.html)), discussed in a [Blog post](https://typo3.com/blog/ddev-adds-support-for-typo3-cms/) by the TYPO3 GmbH and demonstrated in this [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZVMPoI9SIk).

Comment: I can also recommend using DDEV by Drud which also uses Docker and is super simple to set up: https://github.com/drud/ddev Big plus: it directly supports TYPO3!